# Set inputbox value through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Below is my actual `<script>` tag on one page with inputbox in HTML's body tag-

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    window.onload =
        function addSearchText() { 
            document.getElementById("searchterms").value = 'Enter Search Term';
        }
        function removeSearchText() {
            document.getElementById("searchterms").value ="";     
        }
</script>

<form >
    <input type="text" name="searchTerms" id="searchterms" class="inptBx" onfocus="removeSearchText();"/>
    <html:image pageKey="img.common.catalogsearch_button" styleClass="btnGo" />
    <div id="SuggestionListDiv"></div>
</form>
```

When I put some text in input box it searches for it in database through ajax and brings the data in `<ol>
    <li id="1">sam</li>
    <li id="2">joe</li>
    <li id="3">dan</li>
    <li id="4">tom</li>
    <li id="5">dick</li>
</ol>` this format in a dropdown. Now if I select any value say "tom" then it should be set into the inputbox.
Can anybody suggest how to achive this through simple javascript also I have no control on the `<ol><li>` which are generating.
Please suggest
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

Without using jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form> 
    <input type="text" name="searchTerms" id="searchterms" class="inptBx" />
    <html:image pageKey="img.common.catalogsearch_button" styleClass="btnGo" /> 
    <div id="SuggestionListDiv">
        <ol> 
            <li id="1">sam</li> 
            <li id="2">joe</li> 
            <li id="3">dan</li> 
            <li id="4">tom</li>
            <li id="5">dick</li>
        </ol>
    </div> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var searchterms, suggestionList;

        searchterms = document.getElementById('searchterms');
        suggestionList = document.getElementById('SuggestionListDiv');

        if (searchterms && suggestionList) {
            searchterms.value = 'Enter Search Term';

            searchterms.onfocus = function removeSearchText() { 
                searchterms.value = ""; 
            };

            suggestionList.onclick = function setSearchTerms (e) {
                var targ;
                var e = e || window.event;

                if (e.target) {
                    targ = e.target;
                }
                else if (e.srcElement) {
                    targ = e.srcElement;
                }

                // defeat Safari bug 
                if (targ.nodeType === 3) {
                    targ = targ.parentNode;
                }

                if (targ && targ.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li' && targ.hasChildNodes()) {
                    searchterms.value = targ.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                }
            };
        }
    }());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm assuming the li elements have one text node and I am ensuring that I can get the target on (almost) all browsers. If you use jQuery you could just attach the event handler with jQuery and assume that e.target will be correct. When you update the inner contents of the div the event handler still works.

Answer (score 1):

So upon selection u want the text content of the li elements stored in your input box right?
Add an `onclick` event to the `li` elements.

eg: if the content is generated dynamically,

`<li onclick='setSelectedItem(this)'>tom</li>` or like this,

```
var arr = document.getElementById("SuggestedListDiv").getElementsByTagName("ol")[0].getElementsByTagName("li")
for(var in arr)
{
  arr[i].onclick = function(){
   setSelectedItem(this)
  }
}
```

Where,

```
function setSelectedItem(elem)
{
   document.getElementById("searchterms").value = elem.textContent; //elem.innerText for IE
}
```

**EDIT** : Check out how the list element is obtained. First the DIV, Then the ordered list element then comes the `li` within it. Add this, it will work fine.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, I don't have control on generating `<li>`, I think I have to capture that onClick event and then set it to that inputbox.

Comment: I have edited it again, see if its pertinent to your case. You let your li elements get populated. Once thats over, u loop through these elements and assign an onclick event to each - my second scenario.

Comment: Don't add event handlers to the li elements, add the click event handler to the container.

Comment: Adding event handlers to all of the elements is inefficient and too many people end up doing this. You can just attach a single onclick event handler to the container div and test e.target. This way of thinking when it comes to event handling needs to be strongly discouraged imo. edit: it also means the event handlers do not need to be reattached when the container contents are changed with the ajax update

Comment: This most certainly doesnt warrant a downvote. I have not said anything thats wrong or inaccurate. If you want to start your propaganda, write your answer and explain to the OP why your answer its better than what the others have written.

Comment: @me232 can you please elaborate by giving specific answer.

Comment: @TheExplosiveOne - I did the way u have suggested but its not working :(  I have replaced "containeroftheli" with "SuggestionListDiv"

Comment: @SwapnilR. Make sure your traversal is proper and your looping sequence is after the Ajax request is completed and the elements are pasted.

Comment: Make sure you traverse the dom properly div>ol>li heres a sample for you to look at http://jsfiddle.net/BEm7S/. I have also edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

using jquery you can try this:

```
$(li).live('click',function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var label = $(this).text();
$("#searchTerms").val(label);
});
```

Comment: how did you do this? to use jquery plugins/function you need to include jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

In classic Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('SuggestionListDiv').innerHTML(AjaxResponse); //Where AjaxResponse is the response from AJAX call
```

In jQuery :

```
$('#SuggestionListDiv').html(AjaxResponse); //Where AjaxResponse is the response from AJAX call
```

Comment: No, I have to do it only when I got the ajax response, it is coming through some other technology, when I click say suppose "tom" then that value should be given to the inputbox.

Comment: You want to know the AJAX call ? or what to do with the response ?

Comment: No, I dont want to know that. When the "SuggestionListDiv" shows the values I wanted to capture my click and set it in inputbox.

Comment: Then the solution proposed by TheExplosiveOne is probably the best one.